# Solve the quadratic with 4 unknowns

Tags: quadratics

I know how to solve quadratic equations with the quadratic formula but this question has really got me stumped.

$$h=-16t^2+vt+s.$$

I am trying to solve for t but I have no idea where to start since there are 4 variables. Could somebody give a step by step walkthrough to get to a solution for t?

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "solve"?  The quadratic formula works perfectly well here, just apply it to $-16t^2+vt+(s-h)=0$.  But of course the answer will depend on $v,s,h$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
 & h = -16t^{2} + vt + s \\
\implies & 16t^{2} - vt + (h -s) = 0
\end{align}

Comparing this with the standard form of $ax^{2} + bx + c = 0$, the roots will be (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) for details)

\begin{equation}
t = \dfrac{v \pm \sqrt{(-v)^{2} - 4\times 16 \times(h-s)}}{2\times 16} = \dfrac{v \pm \sqrt{v^{2} - 64(h-s)}}{32}
\end{equation}.

Answer (score 1):

writing as $$t^2-\frac{v}{16}t-\frac{s-h}{16}=0$$ and now using the quadratic formula:
$$t_{1,2}=\frac{v}{32}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{v}{32}\right)^2+\frac{s-h}{16}}$$